# Adding records to shared memory table with memcpy()

Tags: c, posix, valgrind

I am trying to write a function that writes a record to a shared memory object but I keep getting segfaults. when I debug with valgrind it says "Use of uninitialised value of size 8". this is the code below.

these are my structs in my header file (i know i'm not consistent with camel case and underscores sorry not sorry) The last two pointers in table_t point to the part of the shared memory that holds the data blocks/records(void* db) and the area that holds information on each record (db_info* dbInfo).

```
typedef struct{
  int dbInfoId;
  int deleted;
}db_info;

typedef struct{
  int shm_fd;
  int numP;
  int control_id;
  char *name;
  int record_size;
  int max_records;
  db_info* dbInfo;
  void* db;
}table_t;


typedef struct{
  int id;
  void* record;
}data_block;
```

this is the add_record function. added some printf statements so I know how far the code gets before the errors start, and to print certain information.

```
int add_record(table_t *tbl, void *record, int record_size){
  printf("code gets this far\n");
  size_t size = sizeof(record_size);
  data_block* rec;
  db_info* recInfo;

  tbl->control_id += 1;
  printf("cid %d\n", tbl->control_id);
  printf("code reaches this point\n");

  /*according to valgrind issuse start here*/

  rec->id = tbl->control_id;
  printf("rec id %d", rec->id);

  rec->record = record;
  printf("code reaches this point\n");

  memcpy(tbl->db, rec, size);

  recInfo->dbInfoId = rec->id;
  recInfo->deleted = 1;

  tbl->db += sizeof(rec);
  tbl->dbInfo += sizeof(recInfo);
  return rec->id;
```

here's whats in my main that im using in the add function

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "data_table.h"
#define MAX_RECORDS 2000000
#define RECORD_SIZE 1024
#define SHM_NAME "abe"

int main(){
  table_t* tbl;
  table_t controlBlock;
  db_info info;
  int com;
  int loop = 0;
  int recId;
  char* rec = "hello world";

  tbl = open_table(SHM_NAME, RECORD_SIZE, MAX_RECORDS);
  printf("this is the number of processes %d\n", tbl->numP);

  tbl->name = SHM_NAME;
 /*this is where i set the pointers to their required locations*/
  tbl->dbInfo = tbl + sizeof(controlBlock);
  tbl->db = tbl + sizeof(tbl->dbInfo);

 /*printing out the different address locations*/
  printf("This is the cb %d, This is the dbInfo %d, and this is the db %d\n",
  &tbl, &tbl->dbInfo, &tbl->db);
 /* my loop. I havent finished all the commands yet*/
  while(loop == 0){
    printf("enter a command (just the number):\n");
    printf("1. Add\n2. Delete\n3. Process\n4. Close\n5. # of processes\n");
    printf("6. exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &com);
    if(com == 1){
      recId = add_record(tbl, rec, RECORD_SIZE);
      printf("record added ID: %d\n", &recId);
    }
    else if(com == 4){
      close_table(tbl);
      loop++;
    }
    else if(com == 5){
      printf("process count %d\n", tbl->numP);
    }
    else if(com == 6){
      loop++;
    }

    }
```

and finally here are the errors from valgrind

```
this is the number of processes 4
This is the cb -16777872, This is the dbInfo 90521632, and this is the db 90521640
enter a command (just the number):
1. Add
2. Delete
3. Process
4. Close
5. # of processes
6. exit
1
code gets this far
cid 4
code reaches this point
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108BDA: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108BE0: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108BFD: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
rec id 4code reaches this point
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C366F2: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C36702: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C36707: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C36729: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x4C36750: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x4C36753: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C3675F: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108C2C: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108C32: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4042==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x1088A0
==4042==    at 0x108C32: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
--4042-- REDIR: 0x50db950 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c30cd0 (free)
==4042== 
==4042== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4042==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4042==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 2,048 bytes allocated
==4042== 
==4042== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4042== 
==4042== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==4042== ERROR SUMMARY: 14 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 1 of 12:
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108C32: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 2 of 12:
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108C2C: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 3 of 12:
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x4C36750: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 4 of 12:
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C36729: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 5 of 12:
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C36707: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 6 of 12:
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C36702: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 7 of 12:
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C366F2: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 8 of 12:
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108BFD: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 9 of 12:
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108BE0: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 1 errors in context 10 of 12:
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x108BDA: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 2 errors in context 11 of 12:
==4042== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4042==    at 0x4C3675F: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== 
==4042== 2 errors in context 12 of 12:
==4042== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4042==    at 0x4C36753: memmove (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4042==    by 0x108C27: add_record (in /home/abiodun/Documents/Comp 3713/Assignment3_makeup/main)
==4042==    by 0x108DAA: main (main.c:35)
==4042== 
==4042== ERROR SUMMARY: 14 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know this is alot and ive probs made tons of errors, but i've never worked with shared memory before and have been trying to figure this out for hours.

This is the open_table function. it was working before but now i'm getting a segfault so i'm not sure.

```
table_t *open_table(char *name, int record_size, int max_records){

  int shm_fd;
  int table_size;
  void* ptr;
  table_t* tbl;
  table_t controlBlock;
  db_info info;
  data_block data;

  table_size = max_records * sizeof(controlBlock) * sizeof(info) *
    sizeof(data);



  if((shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666)) == -1){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ftruncate(shm_fd, table_size);
  ptr = mmap(NULL, table_size, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 
  0);
  tbl = ptr;
  tbl->shm_fd = shm_fd;

  tbl->max_records = max_records;
  tbl->record_size = record_size;
  if(tbl->numP >= 1){
    tbl->numP += 1;
  }
  else{
    tbl->numP = 1;
  }

  return tbl;
}
```

sorry for the mess of code

Comment: I think we need to see `open_table()` too?

Comment: Review `rec->id = tbl->control_id;`.  `rec` is uninitialized at this point so `rec->id` is UB.  Do you have all compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: i've added the open_table @SteveFriedl

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica but I thought setting it equal to the control_id was initializing the rec_id. rec is of type struct data_block and i set both variables equal to something before trying to use them.

Comment: Abe,  Do you have all compiler warnings enabled?  [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10375999/abe) is unclear. The is no `rec_id`.  " rec is of type struct data_block" is incorrect.  `rec` is a pointer to `data_block`.  "i set both variables" is unclear.  The pointer `rec` is not set before attempting `rec->id = tbl->control_id;`

Comment: sorry I meant rec->id. I sort of found a solution. apparently I had to malloc the rec variable before i could access its inner variables (if that makes sense).